# Prevent guest users to Sync

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, onedrive-for-business

What settings do I need to check to prevent guests from syncing files from a Team Site (no office group)?

The feature I'm talking about was requested here

https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913522-onedrive-on-windows/suggestions/7881969-allow-external-onedrive-for-business-users-to-sync

It looks like it is enabled by default now,  and we want to prevent this.
I don't see any settings under the sharing policies.

Is there a PowerShell command to disable it tenant wide or per site?

Comment: The feature request that you linked to is for OneDrive for Business, not SharePoint team sites. That is confusing.

Comment: I thought One drive for business connected to Team sites?

Comment: OneDrive for Business uses the SharePoint engine to store files, but it's the underlying tech and not the same UI as SharePoint. Teams uses SharePoint to store files. Each Team has a SharePoint site with a Documents library and the Teams channels are folders in that library. Teams has no connection to OneDrive for Business.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can disable the Sync for the guest users, but perhaps other options will work. Here is what [another Greg is suggesting](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-disable-sync-in-sharepoint-and-onedrive/):

**Option 1: Disable sync at the library level**

- Navigate to the library where you want to disable sync, then click Gear Icon > Library Settings
- Click on Advanced Settings
- Scroll down to the middle of the page, and under Offline Client Availability, select No (default is Yes)
- Click OK at the bottom
- You will now notice that the library lacks a Sync Button

**Option 2: Disable sync at the Site level**

- Navigate to the site where you want to disable synchronization. Click Gear Icon > Site -Information
- Click View all site settings. If on the classic wiki page, you can click Gear Icon > Site Settings instead of these two steps.
- Click on Search and offline availability under Search
- Under Offline Client Availability select No (default is Yes)
- Click OK at the bottom of the page

**How to disable sync of user’s OneDrive**

- App Launcher > Admin
- Navigate to OneDrive Admin Centre
- Click **Sync**, then check **Allow syncing only joined to specific domains** checkbox then
- Specify the list of domains you want to allow to sync.
- click Save.

Comment: We'd like to keep the ability for our users to sync,  just disable it for guests outside of our organisation

Comment: Yes, Greg, I understand. But these are the only options I know.

Comment: The last one @DenisMolodtsov listed should do the trick - if your users computers are joined to a domain.